# Clear memory and recent task automatically after an app is closed using Tasker

Tags: applications, tasker, recents-screen

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S3 on Android 4.1.2 JellyBean. I would want to create a profile which clears memory and recent tasks when an app is closed (example: Chrome).

Is it possible to do it without root access?

Comment: What do you mean clear "memory" and "recent tasks"? Do you mean history and cookies/cache?

Comment: Sorry for not beeing clear! I want it to clear ram memory and close recent apps!

Comment: There is not a way to clear recent tasks without root(possibly at all) but in theory you could clear memory by killing all apps on app close. I can provide an answer for that if you like.

Comment: Yeah it would be great thanks! I have on other small question ... i've made a pop up when i launch chrome to ask me if i want to load some tabs. I'd like to specify that i want it to show only on app launch not every time the app is "loaded", it's kind of annoying because if i press the home button and do something on the homescreen's and get back into the app it pop's up again!

Answer (score 1):

I use Clean Master for this.

You can invoke separate parts of by holding the clean master button when using the launch app function.

then I used this booster[image: booster]

and I used this process cleaner
[image: process cleaner]

I know this works because I have an app that crashes on startup if there is insufficient RAM. When I use this it never crashes.

I hope it helps, even after two years.

Answer (score 0):

I use Advanced Task Manager and Auto-Shortcut in Tasker to Kill apps.

For your other question, you could create a variable "%Chrome=1" the first time you launch it, and only pop up the menu if the variable is set. On exit, wait a couple minutes then clear %Chrome again.

Answer (score 0):

To clear ram memory You can use [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify). It also supports non rooted phone.

Few things from the app description:

1. Unlike the "Freeze" feature in "TitaniumBackup Pro" that totally
   disable the app, you can still use your app as usual, share content
   with it. No need to freeze & defrozen it.
2. Unlike "Autostarts", you can benefit from almost all of its
   advantages, without needing to deal with the complexity and risk of
   obscure app components, and never lose functionality when app is
   actively running.
3. Unlike any "XXX Task Killer", your device will never fall into the
   cat-mouse-game of stealthy-running and aggressive killing, which
   unnecessarily consumes more battery juice.